# Overriding 3rd party library type (SHARED->STATIC)

Tags: cmake

I use git submodules in my application. One of submodules used as `add_directory(...)` provides a shared library, but I need a static one.

Is it possible to change the library's type from a calling `CMakeLists.txt`? Something like `set_target_properties(...)`.

Comment: is it an owner library or an opensource one, or what kind of license ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to change a library type after `add_library` has been called.

If 3d-party project uses `add_library` **without** specifying its type, then the library of the *default* type is created. That is, you may change default type of the library **before** inclusion of the 3d-party project, and this type will be preserved:

```
# Build static libraries by default
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF) 
# ...
# 'other_project' will build static libraries by default
add_subdirectory(other_project)
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately in my case that library defines its type.

Comment: You may try to **redefine** `add_library` command, so new command will use `STATIC` instead of `SHARED`. You may base on [that mailing](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake-developers/2013-May/019033.html) when implement redefinition.